# How "show inventory" displays SX SFP?

Tags: cisco, router, interface, hardware, transceiver

I've a Cisco 3925 and it's not quite clear why an "1000BASE-SX SFP" entry is visible in the inventory. Is it only visible when the SX SFP is in use? (I've no chance to modify it.)

```
NAME: "CISCO3925-CHASSIS", DESCR: "CISCO3925-CHASSIS"
PID: CISCO3925-CHASSIS , VID: V02

NAME: "Cisco Services Performance Engine 100 for Cisco 3900 ISR on Slot 0", DESCR: "Cisco Services Performance Engine 100 for Cisco 3900 ISR"
PID: C3900-SPE100/K9   , VID: V01

**NAME: "1000BASE-SX SFP", DESCR: "1000BASE-SX SFP"
PID: GLC-SX-MMD        , VID: 001**

NAME: "C3900 AC Power Supply 1", DESCR: "C3900 AC Power Supply 1"
PID: PWR-3900-AC       , VID: V02
```

---

```
Gi0/0   << RJ45
Gi0/1   << Combo port using RJ45
Gi0/2   << Combo port using SX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an SFP module inserted, you will see the specific type.

You can choose to specifically use the inserted SFP, or choose to use the built-in copper connector, with the `media-type` interface command:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 media-type sfp
```

or

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 media-type rj45
```